# autokeras fit function with datagen

Tags: auto-keras

I am interested in using autokeras for NAS. From the documentation it looks like the .fit method (in class ImageClassifier) may not accept objects of the ImageDataGenerator class for training and validation data. Is this right? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the autokeras team and their reply is: Currently, we don't have plans for implementing this.